# Opportunity team filtering users

Tags: user, opportunity-teams

I'm trying to collect only those users who are ACTIVE and filter out non-active users. Can I filter out users from the following opportunityTeamQuery string that holds a query?

```
String opportunityTeamQuery = CUSTOMSETTING_Queries__c.getValues('CUSTOMSETTING_12').myQuery__c+' '+ 'where 
    (OpportunityAccessLevel =\''+ Opportunity Team +'\' or UserId =\''+oppor.ownerID+'\')and opportunityID=\''+oppor.id+'\''; 

where ...

myQuery__c=select OpportunityAccessLevel, UserId from OpportunityTeamMember

oppor = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
CL00203 value=edit
```

**EDIT**

I'm trying to retrieve active users only. How can I achieve this with this dynamic SOQL?

```
 String opportunityTeamQuery = CUSTOMSETTING_Queries__c.getValues('CUSTOMSETTING_12').myQuery__c+' '+ 'where (OpportunityAccessLevel =\''+ Opportunity Team +'\' or UserId =\''+oppor.ownerID+'\')and opportunityID=\''+oppor.id+'\''and User.IsActive=true;

where ...

myQuery__c=select OpportunityAccessLevel, UserId from OpportunityTeamMember

oppor = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord(); CL00203 value=edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query for to filter only active Team Members

> Select o.User.IsActive, o.UserId, o.OpportunityId, o.Id From OpportunityTeamMember o where o.User.IsActive=true

You will have to just convert to dynamic query in your case

Comment: Thanks for answering. So what is "o"?

Comment: its just variable you can remove all o's no problems.If the issue resolves mark as answered

Comment: i have made changes as per your reply. But getting an error Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'and' at line 100 column 222  if I add like this.....String opportunityTeamQuery = CUSTOMSETTING_Queries__c.getValues('CUSTOMSETTING_12').myQuery__c+' '+ 'where 
    (OpportunityAccessLevel =\''+ Opportunity Team +'\' or UserId =\''+oppor.ownerID+'\')and opportunityID=\''+oppor.id+'\''and User.IsActive=true; It will be very kind of you if u helped. Thanks

Comment: Turn your logs on and debug .Looks like your query formation is missing proper syntax